# How do I create a Rails 4 model that is a hybrid between local records and remote resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, models, activeresource

I'm working on a social movie app in Rails. I do not wish to start from scratch on a database of movie info, so I've found a free and community-maintained movie database called The Movie Database (TMDB). It has a good API and documentation.

How would I design a Rails model that could be fully associated with my user model that can use a local record from my movies table, but if that record isn't there, make an API call to get the info?

I did a little research and it sounds like ActiveResource might do part of what I want, but it doesn't really offer associations with ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how are you querying your local database to see if a movie is there and, if not, querying the api. Ideally, you should use the same ids from the api locally (maybe on a imdb_id field?) and query movies from there:

```
m = Movie.from_imdb_id(832903820)
```

where:

```
def self.from_imdb_id(imdb_id)
  m = Movie.where(imdb_id: imdb_id).first
  if m.blank?
    # I dont know how the api queries work so suggesting something here:
    data = RestClient.get("http://api.tmdb.com/movies/#{imdb_id}.json")
    m = Movie.create!(data.merge(imdb_id: imbd_id)
  end
  return m
end
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I came up with. I was mostly curious if there were other ways I should be considering, especially since I'm not too familiar with ActiveResource, which seems to pretty much do what I want except relate to ActiveRecord models.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Movie.find_or_create_by(imdb_id: imdb_id) do |movie|
  data = RestClient.get("http://api.tmdb.com/movies/#{imdb_id}.json")
  movie.director = data['director']
  .....
end
```

It would find a record corresponding to imdb_id, if not, would create a new one with the parameters in the block.

Regards!